# Function to hide apps in Slingshot

Tags: slingshot

[image: Missing feature]

I miss a function to hide some applications in Slingshot.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting/moving desktop entries in `/usr/share/applications` or `/usr/local/share/applications` has one major downside:

Everytime one of your "hidden" applications gets an update, it will reappear in Slingshot.

There is a more convenient and permanent way to hide your applications:
Install and run `menulibre` from the official repositories. Within this application you can enable *Hide from menus* to hide every entry, which you want to disperse.

[image: MenuLibre]

Unlike [Zzzach...'s solution](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2185/22) *MenuLibre* doesn't remove the hidden entries, it creates a copy in your local application entries folder `~/.local/share/applications` and adds the following line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

The global desktop entry stays untouched and gets overriden by your local copy. An update of your hidden application will only overwrite the global entry, so this application will stay hidden.

But I have to agree with you, a *hide* right click menu entry would be the most convenient way :)

Comment: Excellent solution. I wish I knew this before! I'm used to deleting their .desktop files.

Answer (score 1):

May not be what you want, but here's a guide:

You can manually remove (or move, if you want it to be temporary) the plethora of .desktop files found in either `/usr/share/applications` or `/usr/local/share/applications`. Most of these "shortcuts", or rather, .desktop files, are located in these two directories. Using administrative privileges, you can move these ".desktop" files into another directory for safe keeping, or remove them completely.

Run `sudo xdg-open /usr/share/applications` to open an administrative Files viewer that starts at the shortcuts folder.

[image: Administrative Files Window]

You should see something like this.
Move and remove as you want, just be careful when removing. It's hard to get them back without reinstalling the application.

Comment: Ouh... Okey thx.That was a great help. But I wish me a easier way in elementary os ( Like in my example) to hide unuse or background  applications ( Sry for my english, I understand you but I can't realy wirte in english.)

Comment: @MichaelSchirrmeister - Rafael's answer above is better, as it is persistent through app updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a menu editor like `menulibre` or `alacarte` to edit and hide application shortcuts in slingshot.

The context menu is a good idea, though.